# Do all magika recovery skills boost recovery in combat?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

The Light Armor skill, Recovery, "increases magika regeneration".

The Altmer racial skill, Spellcharge, increases "magika recovery in combat"

Do these distinctions mean that the Recovery skill does not affect magika recovery rate while in combat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any effect which states that it increases recovery of an attribute, without further qualification, increases it both in-combat and out. Anything that is specific to one or the other will say so.